# How to call setInterval only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a counter that should update count by 1 each seconds the user inputed.

In my code I have 2 logs, the 1st one when the interval start, and the seconds one when I need to clearInterval.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [ms, setMS] = useState(1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Start inteval");
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, ms);

    return () => {
      console.log("Clear interval");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [ms]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={ms} onChange={(e) => setMS(e.target.value)}></input>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is, that the line console.log("Start inteval"); is colled every time when I update the count.

For example if the time for delay is 1 seconds , so the console.log("Start inteval"); will called every second.

I need to call it only once, is this possible ? But the counter should run...

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) from source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout to run code only once at delay

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

you can use set interval and reset timer

```
let timer= setInterval(function() {
  console.log('timer');
  clearTimeout(remaingTime);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi @Dibash sapkota ,  you not understand , I need to run it in intervals for 1 seconds.

Comment: you can use set interval and reset timer

Answer (score 0):

That can be solved with a `flag`. The code turns like this:

```
default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [ms, setMS] = useState(1000);
  let first = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      first && console.log("Start inteval");
      first = false;
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, ms);

    return () => {
      console.log("Clear interval");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [ms]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={ms} onChange={(e) => setMS(e.target.value)}></input>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
const App=()=> {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [ms, setMS] = useState(1000);
  const [prev ,setPrev] = useState(ms)

  const changeMs = (e) => {
    setMS(e)
    setPrev(e)
  }

  const runInterval = () => {
    setPrev("stop")

    if(prev===ms)
    {
      console.log("start Interval")
    }
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);

  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(runInterval, ms);
    return () => {
      console.log("clear interval")
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [ms,prev]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={ms} onChange={(e) => changeMs(e.target.value)}></input>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will run **start interval** in console only once after **ms** is changed